# Unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.int64

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am using the [timedelta function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) from datetime package to convert seconds into hours and minutes format.

Here's an example:

```
secs = timedelta(seconds = 30)
print(secs)

00:00:30
```

When is run this on a pandas column that I need to convert, I run into the unsupported type error. It looks like this happens when it the function encounters a '0' and is not sure how to handle it, I think.

```
EmpComm = pd.DataFrame({
         'Duration (secs)':[3488, 2994,0, 0],
         'Duration (hh:mm)':['0:58:08','0:49:54',np.nan,np.nan],

})
print (EmpComm)
   Duration (secs) Duration (hh:mm)
0             3488          0:58:08
1             2994          0:49:54
2                0              NaN
3                0              NaN
```

[image: Data sample]

I am wondering why it isn't able to convert seconds = 0 to 00:00:00. Here's my code:

```
for i, row in EmpComm.iterrows():

    val = timedelta(seconds = EmpComm['Duration (secs)'].iloc[i])
    EmpComm['Duration (hh:mm)'][i] = val
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dont use loops with `iterrows`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316), because exist vectorized solution.

You need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with parameter `unit`:

```
EmpComm = pd.DataFrame({
         'Duration (secs)':[3488, 2994,0, 0],
         'Duration (hh:mm)':['0:58:08','0:49:54',np.nan,np.nan],

})

EmpComm['Duration (hh:mm)'] = pd.to_timedelta(EmpComm['Duration (secs)'], unit='s')
print (EmpComm)
   Duration (secs) Duration (hh:mm)
0             3488         00:58:08
1             2994         00:49:54
2                0         00:00:00
3                0         00:00:00
```